# how to type strong params in rails api / sorbet / tapioca

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

i'm trying to start a new project where i play with typing and i'm having a hard time getting the basic API stuff to work.

here is the code from my controller:

```rb
# typed: strict

module Api
  module V1
    class PlayersController < ApplicationController
      extend T::Sig

      sig { returns(String) }
      def create
        player = Player.create(player_params)

        render json: player
      end

      private

      sig { returns(ActionController::Parameters) }
      def player_params
        params.require(:player).permit(:name, :email)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

i'm getting an error on the `permit` call.

```
Method `permit` does not exist on `String` component of
`T.any(String, Numeric, T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters)`
```

i've tried passing in `params` into the `player_params` method and assigning it to a variable that has a type of `ActionController::Parameters`, but that didn't work either.

if there's a doc or suggestion, i'd love to learn where i'm going wrong!

[image: screenshot of vscode if that helps]

for additional context i am using in my gemfile

```
gem 'sorbet', :group => :development
gem 'sorbet-runtime'
gem 'tapioca', require: false, :group => :development
```

Comment: Do you know why `params.require()` is outputting a string? Rails builds `params` as `ActionController::Parameters`, so something bad must be happening. Is `params` without the `.require` a string?

Comment: `sorbet` uses a method called `params`, so they might be colliding: https://sorbet.org/docs/sigs#params-annotating-parameter-types

Comment: Are you using [`sorbet-rails`](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sorbet-rails)?

Comment: https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sorbet-rails#controllers

Comment: @Chiperific thanks for the replies!

i am not using sorbet-rails but i will check those docs out just in case. i was curious if i would have to declare the structure in advance like that, so i'll give that a shot.

i am using tapioca and sorbet

Comment: I'm hoping the issue is that `sorbet` is overriding the `params` variable and that `sorbet-rails` solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so i was close when i was trying to assign the `params` variable to a typed variable.

solution:

```rb
def player_params
  player_params = T.cast(params.require(:player), ActionController::Parameters)

  player_params.permit(:name, :email)
end
```

> require can return any of those types T.any(String, Numeric,
> T::Array[T.untyped], ActionController::Parameters). As Sorbet can't
> know which one will be returned at runtime it try to see if the method
> called on that return exists in all types, which clearly don't.
>
> To fix you need to tell sorbet what the return of require is going to
> be at runtime using T.cast

i ended up asking on the repo: https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/issues/1122

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you think using Sorbet is worth it?

Comment: @Eyeslandic, i'm still pretty new to sorbet w/ruby but i think so. it's pretty neat and i've seen how useful typing can be with typescript. it looks ugly as sin right now though, so hopefully i adjust to it like i did with TS, haha. the tooling is pretty slick though once it's all setup.

Comment: @Eyeslandic I have mixed feelings about Sorbet. On one hand, it makes you write safer code; on the other hand it takes away the "Happiness" philosophy that underpins the Ruby language.